# Space Time Cube in ArcMap, always get invalid file format for output

Tags: arcgis-desktop, file-formats, space-time-cube, error-000814

I am using ArcMap 10.4.1 on Windows 7 to try and create a space time cube to model wildfire spatial/temporal patterns across a portion of Colorado.

I always get the error 000814 Invalid file type in the output Space Time Cube. The output is a netCDF file, and it's extension is .nc

I don't understand why I am getting this error, please see attached screen shot.
I try and create the output with the .nc extension and without it, and I get the same error either way. I have also tried to add other extensions like .shp just to see what happens and always the same error.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. It just couldn't save it inside the geodatabase. It worked saving it like this, saving it inside the folder that held that geodatabase.

[image]